# Can't get else if condition to work with image in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an image appear when the three conditions are met but I only get the BMW image displayed. I just can't seem to see why the else if doesn't work, maybe just looked at it to long. Searched for an other way but didn't find.

```
var name = prompt("Hello there, what's your name?");
var car = new Array("BMW", "Maserati");
var randomCar = Math.floor(Math.random()*car.length);
var carName = car[randomCar];

if(name === "Frank" || name === "Chris" && carName === "BMW") {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + " you have won a " + carName + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/bmw.jpg' alt='BMW Pic' style='border-radius: 10px;'</h1>";
} else if (name === "Frank" || name === "Chris" && carName === "Maserati") {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + " you have won a " + carName + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/maserati.jpg' alt='Maserati Pic' style='border-radius: 10px;'</h1>";
} else {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + ", no car for you today !!" + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/pitbull-sad-face.jpg' alt='Dog sadface' style='width: 70%; border-radius: 20px;'</h1>";
};
```

Comment: Maybe those images don't exist. You haven't closed your img tag BTW

Comment: Can you add the input parameters (`name` and `carName`)  to your question?

Comment: The code does [seem to work](https://jsfiddle.net/h3vtajrg/) ?

Comment: yeah i got that it worked too https://jsfiddle.net/kszmd7e0/

Comment: The code works as is.

Comment: Try it when the name is "Frank".

Answer (score 1):

The tested expression in your `if` statement:

```
(name === "Frank" || name === "Chris" && carName === "BMW")
```

is evaluated as if it were written:

```
(name === "Frank" || (name === "Chris" && carName === "BMW"))
```

That is, the `&&` part is evaluated such that the test will succeed if the name is "Frank" *or* if the name is "Chris" and also the car name is "BMW". If the name is "Frank", then the car name doesn't matter; it only matters when the name is "Chris".

If you want the name to always matter, you have to explicitly parenthesize the two tests for the name:

```
((name === "Frank" || name === "Chris") && carName === "BMW")
```

Now it will succeed only if the name is either "Frank" or "Chris" *and* if the car name is "BMW".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it clear for me! Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

It's your order of operations. What is happening is that your logic says `if frank, or if Chris+BMW` when you really want `if Frank+BMW or if Chris+BMW`. Put parentheses around the `or` (`||`) parts.

```
if((name === "Frank" || name === "Chris") && carName === "BMW") {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + " you have won a " + carName + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/bmw.jpg' alt='BMW Pic' style='border-radius: 10px;'</h1>";
} else if ((name === "Frank" || name === "Chris") && carName === "Maserati") {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + " you have won a " + carName + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/maserati.jpg' alt='Maserati Pic' style='border-radius: 10px;'</h1>";
} else {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello " + name + ", no car for you today !!" + "<br><br>" + "<img src='img/pitbull-sad-face.jpg' alt='Dog sadface' style='width: 70%; border-radius: 20px;'</h1>";
};
```

Right now, Frank will always get a BMW because the first `if` statement passes as true because `name==="Frank"`.

Comment: Thank you Devin, it can be so simple but I just didn't see. Thanx for explaining!